# When a function is added to $.special.event - postDispatch called twice

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Am trying to add a common functionality to jquery click event and I want a function to be called when a click event is triggered. So my code looks like this

```
$.event.special.click = {

      postDispatch: function(event) {
        console.log('postdispatch')
      }

    };
```

This function is fired post a click event is triggered. But the issue is its called twice. Is there anyway we can prevent the second call.

Comment: I only see it once.  http://jsfiddle.net/JSLhd/

Answer (score 0):

Its happening only in my app for now I have added a stoppropagation to stop it.